# Word to describe two processes which function at opposing times

Tags: synonyms

I'm drafting up a workflow report that I need to present in a meeting tomorrow and I'm reaching for a word, it's on the tip of my tongue but it's alluding me.

I'm writing about two processes which run over the course of two weeks and repeat, over and over again.  The first process starts, and the second starts one week into the first and ends one week into the next.  So the two processes run parallel but always one week apart.

A crude example:

Process 1: a a a **a** b b b **b** c c c **c** d d d **d**

Process 2: .....  1 1 1 **1** 2 2 2 **2** 3 3 3 **3** 4 4 4 **4**

*notice 1 starts after a is half thru and ends in the middle of b..  this is the sequence of operation*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider "[**staggered**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stagger) process."

> **stagger**: to arrange otherwise than at the same time, especially in a series of alternating or continually overlapping intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Two parallel, closed-loop processes running simultaneously, with process two commencing concurrent with the mid-point of process one phase one, resulting in a temporal offset of one half phase between the two processes.